# Given a list of strings, how can I determine what the shortest length of differentiation is?

Tags: ruby

Say I have an array of hash strings, e.g.

```
['a04a872ff4027233', '8cef496d2a92808c', etc.]
```

I would like an elegant way to determine what is the shortest uniform-length substring I can use to differentiate between the alternatives.

E.g. if the shortest length substring is 3, then the options could be abbreviated to ['a04', '8ce', etc], and I could then just expand the abbreviation later.

I need a solution in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1...s.first.size).find {|i| !s.map {|j| j[0...i]}.uniq!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very "elegant" per se, but this would work:

```
strings = ['a04a872ff4027233', '8cef496d2a92808c', .....]
count = 1
count += 1 while strings.map{ |item| item[0...count] }.uniq.length != strings.length

count
# => 3

strings.map{ |item| item[0...count] }
# => ['a04', '8ce', ...]
```